# Run Junit test from .jar file shows "Build Successful" also when test failed

Tags: ant, junit, jar

I have created a .jar file that contains a junit test. When I run my Junit test in Ant with task "junit", then it shows me the correct output (BUILD FAILED when the Junit test fails).

But when I put the Junit test into a .jar-file and have this .jar-file run via Ant task "run-jar", then it always shows me "BUILD SUCCESSFUL", even when the Junit test fails. The console output shows me that the test faild, but the message in the end is still "BUILD SUCCESSFUL". Is there a possibility to make the build fail, also when I run the test from the .jar-file?

I already set haltonfailure="no", but it still did not work.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Success means that your Jar is executed. Maybe, you have to wrap your Tase-cases in a TestSuite or something & exit with non-zero in case of failure, for Maven to detect the failure.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. I added a System.exit(1) in case the test failed, but it still showed me the BUILD SUCCESSFUL message. Even when I commented out everything and just let the main method exit with exit status 1, the ant output was:

`jar:
      [jar] Building jar: D:\eclipse-workspaces\...
run-jar:
      [java] Java Result: 1
main:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL`

Comment: Finally we came up to solve the problem by running the ant-file's junit-task again instead of running the executable jar-file. But thank you anyway for your answer!